# Corruption of files in postgres: The database subdirectory "base/13067" is missing

Tags: postgresql, recovery, disaster-recovery, docker

Right, my **PostgreSQL** database 11.1 is on top of a **GlusterFS**.

My **GlusterFS** break, my backup was being done on another table and I don't have backups anymore.

I started the database on a docker container, and i recived some erros:

```
2020-10-07 22:03:43.677 UTC [359] FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist
2020-10-07 22:03:43.677 UTC [359] DETAIL:  The database subdirectory "base/73729" is missing.
```

Basically, I only have the postgres data directory. The files on directory are:

```
base                  opa           pg_ident.conf  pg_replslot   pg_stat_tmp  PG_VERSION            postgresql.conf
core.48               pg_commit_ts  pg_logical     pg_serial     pg_subtrans  pg_wal                postmaster.opts
docker-entrypoint.sh  pg_dynshmem   pg_multixact   pg_snapshots  pg_tblspc    pg_xact               postmaster.pid
global                pg_hba.conf   pg_notify      pg_stat       pg_twophase  postgresql.auto.conf
```

When i try to `pg_dumpall`:

```
pg_dumpall -U user1 -g 
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist
DETAIL:  The database subdirectory "base/73729" is missing.
```

When i try to `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -Uuser1 desired_database
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16385/2839": No such file or directory
LINE 1: ....tableoid, n.oid, n.nspname, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog...
                                                             ^
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT n.tableoid, n.oid, n.nspname, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = nspowner) AS rolname, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(n.nspacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) as nspacl, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(n.nspacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) as rnspacl, NULL as initnspacl, NULL as initrnspacl FROM pg_namespace n LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (n.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_namespace'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0)
```

Theres any way to recovery, make a partial dump or something to extract at least some part of the tables?

Comment: What, if any, files are in the data directory?

Comment: Added the list of files on the question

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what the limit of the corruption is.  If this is the only problem, you should be able to get the globals with:

```
pg_dumpall -g
```

And the data with:

```
pg_dump desired_database
```

If this works, it would allow you to reload your data into a new cluster.

Comment: Nothing change, the `pg_dumpall` is the same. But i updated the post to reflect more data about the error.

Comment: pg_dumpall -g should not try to connect to database `template1`, unless database `postgres` already fails to exist.  It seems like your corruption is more extensive than just one database.